# How to wait for code to run before continuing

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have written a vbscript that will automatically change the theme to my desktop using cmd, and then close the "Personalization" window after it is changed. In order to give enough time to the rest of my code, I place a timer of 3500 ms after a line of code to allow the rest of it to run after it has finished executing. I'm wondering if there is a way to take out the timer but still allow the Personalization window to close automatically after the theme is changed. I tried using a "true" statement at the end of the line, but it doesn't seem to work and the window stays open and I have to manually close it. My code is as follows:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""

Wscript.Sleep 3500
WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties")
WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"
```

Also, I am not sure what the %FC and {F4} mean at the end (some of these lines I got from other sources, but it just seemed to work at the time). Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""

Wscript.Sleep 3500
WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties")
WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"

WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties")
WshShell.Sendkeys "%{F4}"
```

That being said, if you run scripts on your machine you should really know what your code does.  A six line script and you don't know what two of them do is asking for trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to vbs and am still learning, and I've looked around for answers to the last two sendkeys. I know one of them closes the window, but I don't understand why there's two of them. Also, how is this code different from the one I posted though? All that is different is you reactivate the window. I was wondering if there's a way to take out the timer and add something so once the "run" line finishes, THEN it recognizes that and can run the rest of the code. Thank you for the help though, i appreciate it!

Comment: @art123456: You should read the SendKeys documentation here so you will see what is different: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/17420.  I think the first thing you tried, with passing true as the last parameter of Run, probably worked, but the rest of the code didn't shut down the window.